# an over view of sparsity promoting inversion techniques

Tags: sparse-matrix, inverse-problem

I have a function called f(x) which is convex and I can have access to its first order derivative , my objective function is

$$\ J(\bf{x}) = f(\bf{x}) + \lambda |\bf{x}|_0 $$

$$\  \bigtriangledown f(\bf{x}) \space is \space available$$

Could you please provide a list of state of the art methods in the literature that can solve this sparse regularization problem?

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! Such "shopping list" questions are not a good fit for this site (see http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). You will get better answers if you add some detail (context, size of the problem, desired accuracy, performance constraints, whether it has to be $l^0$, etc.) and ask for specific recommendations for your specific problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that in general this problem is intractable (NP-Hard) with the $\| x \|_{0}$ regularization.

Are you willing to consider minimizing

$ f(x) + \lambda \| x \|_{1}$

instead?  There are many methods for the 1-norm regularized problem.  There are also lots of theoretical results that give conditions under which 1-norm minimization produces solutions that are very close to the 0-norm regularized solution.

Comment: Agreed. Last I checked, this general approach was favored in the literature.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I am also looking for the name some state of the art methods on how to solve the l1 norm regularized problem in a general form of f(x) for which first order oracle properties are available.

Comment: See http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/prox_algs.html

Comment: See also http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/admm_distr_stats.html